# Smooth raycast positioning

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting, rigid-bodies

I have written a script to move an object via ray cast to positions on a terrain, however I can’t  for the life of me seem to make this movement smooth. I have tried all manner of things trying to figure this out (as you can probably tell by the amount of commented-out code below); disabling various rigidbody variables, however to no avail.

One approach that (kind of) worked was disabling the collider attached to the object, however this lead to the object inadvertently sinking below the terrain.

Can anyone please advise me as to the best approach to go about this would be? I feel like this should be very simple but I am over complicating it.

```js
         //Move
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) {
          //            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
          //            {
          //                modObj.GetComponent(BoxCollider).enabled = false;               
          initPos = modObj.transform.position;
          var initRotation = modObj.transform.rotation;
          //            }
          //            
          //            modObj.GetComponent(Rigidbody).isKinematic = true;
          //            modObj.GetComponent(Rigidbody).useGravity = false; 

          moveObject(modObj, initPos, initRotation);
        } else {
          //            modObj.GetComponent(BoxCollider).enabled = true;
          //            modObj.GetComponent(Rigidbody).isKinematic = false;
          //            modObj.GetComponent(Rigidbody).useGravity = true; 
        }
```

```js
function moveObject(modObj: GameObject, initPos: Vector3, initRotation: Quaternion) {
  //Debug.Log("Moving Object");

  var hit: RaycastHit;
  var foundHit: boolean = false;

  foundHit = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, hit);
  //Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.blue);

  if (foundHit && hit.transform.tag == "Terrain") {
    modifyObjGUIscript.activateMoveDisplay(initPos, hit.point);

    //      var meshHalfHeight = modObj.GetComponent.<MeshRenderer>().bounds.size.y /2; //helps account for large and small objects

    modObj.transform.position = hit.point; //***method 01***
    //      modObj.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(initPos, hit.point, speed); //***method 02***
    //      modObj.transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(initPos, hit.point, velocity, smoothTime); //***method 02***

    //      modObj.transform.position.y =  modObj.transform.position.y + meshHalfHeight + hoverHeight;

    modObj.transform.rotation = initRotation;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the moveObject to recompute the position very frequently - every frame, if possible. For example from Update or from coroutine:

```
void Update() 
{
    modObj.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(initPos, hit.point, speed); 
}


IEnumerator MoveObject(Vector3 initPos, Vector3 endPos, float speed)
{
    while (initPos != endPos)
    {
    modObj.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(initPos, endPos, speed);
    yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right on.  Note too that very often you do this: have a new independent marker (ie, empty GameObject) called say "Tracker". But a small white cube on it for development purposes so you can see it.  Put Jorel's script on Tracker (NOT ON YOUR ACTUAL AIRPLANE).  Make the user actually steer, etc, Tracker.  Next, have your Airplane actually *follow Tracker everywhere*. In this way you can *smooth the motion on Y* for the airplane; it's often more simple and logical to do this.

Comment: @joreldraw sorry should have been clearer in my post: the `moveObject()` function is being called from the `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)` inside of a `FixedUpdate()`; does this match what you're saying?


I have also changed the positioning from using the object's transform to using its rigidbody: 
`var movRb = modObj.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();`
`movRb.position = Vector3.Lerp(initPos, hit.point, speed);` 
as per some other feedback I have received. This has certainly helped but not resolved the issue. Any further feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: try to call the coroutine with a while condition, i edit the coroutine for this.